# ActionLink generate empty href using MVC 5 with Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using MVC 5 with Umbraco 7. Trying to use ActionLink in my View but the markup it generates have empty href. any idea how to get it working?

```
<a href="">Start Date</a>
```

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
      "Start Date",
      "SearchV1",
      "SearchV1",
      new { sitetypeid = @Request.QueryString["sitetypeid"], leaNo = @Request.QueryString["leaNo"], orderBy = "VacStart" },
      null)
```

Controller:

```
public class SearchV1Controller : RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return base.Index(model);
    }

    public ActionResult SearchV1(RenderModel model, int sitetypeId , int leaNo, string orderBy = "VacRelDate")
    {
        List<GetJobSearchResults_Result> searchResultsList = Workflow.Vacancy.GetJobSearchResults(sitetypeId , leaNo, "SCH", orderBy, "desc");
        ViewBag.leaNo = leaNo;
        return View(searchResultsList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it generate the `href` if you set the route object to `null`?

Comment: Sorry what you mean by Route object ? where do i pass null?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Start Date", "SearchV1", "SearchV1",null, null)`

Comment: Tried that but its still generating empty href   <a href="">Start Date</a>

Comment: FYI - ActionLink attempts to use the route values you give it (including controller and action) to match one of the routes that are configured in the route collection. An empty HREF indicates that none of the routes matched. You need to pass a valid set of route values to see a URL (but since I don't know anything about Umbraco I can't tell you what those route values might be).

Comment: Please add your route configuration. Does any of the action's parameters are part of some route?

Comment: I am using Umbraco so havent got any.

Comment: You cannot use Html.ActionLink, Url.Action or Ajax.ActionLink to link to a page. Why?

First of, umbraco content is content, not actions. All requests are routed to the controllers and actions. Meaning content is delivered by parsing urls -> controller + action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be possible in Umbraco unless you inherit your controller class from Surface controller.