# Custom Controller Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7

I just started learning Umbraco, I have started small project just to learn Umbraco. I am having problem in creating custom controller. I have a link on my page for user to browse all the products:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View more", "Index", "Product", null, new { title = "Browse all Products" })
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {
            return View("Products");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the web page show a the link with blank href

```
<a href="" title="Browse all Products">View more</a>
```

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035660/actionlink-generate-empty-href) your controller has to inherit from **Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController** in order for the route to be picked up.  Is this an option for you?

Comment: Hi,
I have changed it to inherit from SurfaceController. But now when I try to run I get error
HTTP 404 the resouce not found at  /umbraco/Surface
Where as all my views are stored in View folder. Not sure how to change it to look for views in View folder.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarilly have to inherit from `SurfaceController`, as they are typically used for rendering MVC Child Actions and for handling form data submissions. In your case, a controller inheriting from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController` should be enough.

First check the Settings section of Umbraco and make sure that there is a Document Type called `Product`. Umbraco follows this convention for routing, so all pages of type `Product` will be routed to your `ProductController`. This routing convention might also help the `HtmlHelper` construct the action link correctly.

According to the [documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers), the mapping works as follows:

- Document Type name = controller name
- Template name = action name
- if no action matches or is not specified then the 'Index' action will be executed.

Finally, make sure that your controller action returns the template view. For example, if using the default `RenderModel` type, you can simply return the Template view for the document type:

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
{
    return base.Index(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I followed yous instructions , now I am getting error : System.Exception: No physical template file was found for template Product
I have checked in backoffice Umbraco and I cant see anything wromg with it.

Comment: Does you document type have a template named "Product"? Also, can you see a file named "Product.cshtml" within your project's `Views` folder?